# Select-Object - what can I select?

Tags: powershell, select

I'm learning PowerShell and I am stuck at an issue where I have to export something and I don't know its object name.

I use this command:

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Select-Object DisplayName,PrimarySmtpAddress
```

How do I find out what objects I can select with `Select-Object`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get-member will show you all of the properties and methods of an object, but it doesn't show you the values.  To see the values, I recommend using Format-List instead.

For example, Get-ChildItem (Dir) shows you a list of files, but also provides a tremendous amount of other properties we might want.  To see them all, pipe it into format-list.

```
PS C:\temp\NewFolder> dir


Directory: C:\temp\NewFolder


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        7/22/2015  11:31 AM             44 Computers.txt
-a----        7/22/2015  12:37 PM            106 NotepadProfile.ps1
-a----        7/22/2015  11:07 AM             21 Tester.txt
```

Not bad, and a pretty useful listing, but to see everything we have to work with, throwing Format-List (FL) is the way to go.

```
PS C:\temp\NewFolder> dir | format-list *


PSPath            : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\temp\NewFolder\Computers.txt
PSParentPath      : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\temp\NewFolder
PSChildName       : Computers.txt
PSDrive           : C
PSProvider        : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem
PSIsContainer     : False
VersionInfo       : File:             C:\temp\NewFolder\Computers.txt
                    InternalName:
                    OriginalFilename:
                    FileVersion:
                    FileDescription:
                    Product:
                    ProductVersion:
                    Debug:            False
                    Patched:          False
                    PreRelease:       False
                    PrivateBuild:     False
                    SpecialBuild:     False
                    Language:

BaseName          : Computers
Target            :
LinkType          :
Mode              : -a----
Name              : Computers.txt
Length            : 44
DirectoryName     : C:\temp\NewFolder
Directory         : C:\temp\NewFolder
IsReadOnly        : False
Exists            : True
FullName          : C:\temp\NewFolder\Computers.txt
Extension         : .txt
CreationTime      : 7/22/2015 11:13:40 AM
CreationTimeUtc   : 7/22/2015 3:13:40 PM
LastAccessTime    : 7/22/2015 11:13:40 AM
LastAccessTimeUtc : 7/22/2015 3:13:40 PM
LastWriteTime     : 7/22/2015 11:31:33 AM
LastWriteTimeUtc  : 7/22/2015 3:31:33 PM
Attributes        : Archive
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Get-Member`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849928.aspx).

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Get-Member
```

will show you all of the properties (as well as methods and events).